# GPO - File push error 0x80070043 - Unable to find path

Tags: group-policy

I have an issue with pushing a .cmd file by GPO to the computers, with an error 0x80070043 which mean it's unable to find the path.

> I use the GPO : User config / Preference / Files

Here is the settings of the file which will be pushed :

[General settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVq1W.png)

[Common](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxoAb.png)

[Source access authorizations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHg4p.png)

Maybe i'm doing wrong with the path ? Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks !

EDIT : Utilisateurs mean Users , Lecture mean Read , Execution mean Execute

Comment: I tried with putting the Reboot.cmd file on the C:\Exploit of the computer directly and it work. So it's an issue with the source path. 

I already tried to put this : DC.mydomain\c$\Exploit\Reboot.cmd 
But it does'nt work :/

Comment: It works with : "\\SERVERNAME\Exploit\Reboot.cmd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source path is interpreted on the client computers, so `C:\` in that box refers to the C drive of each individual client rather than that of the server. Your clients were trying to copy from their own drive to somewhere else on that drive, so unless you already put the file on the clients' drives, the source didn't exist for them. To deploy a file from a server to clients, you need to have the file on an accessible share and put the UNC path in the source box.

Comment: Thank you for this informations. How can I put the subject to [Resolved ?]

Comment: @Beko You can click the gray check mark next to this answer to indicate that it solves the problem.